# Integer.valueOf() Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, arrays, integer, text-manipulation

```
String currentLine = reader.readLine();
while (currentLine != null)
{
  String[] studentDetail = currentLine.split("");

  String name = studentDetail[0];

  int number = Integer.valueOf(studentDetail[1]);
  currentLine = reader.readLine();
}
```

So I have a file like this:

```
   student1
   student16
   student6
   student9
   student10
   student15
```

When I run the program said:
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1

the output should look like this:

```
   student1
   student6
   student9
   student10
   student11
   student15
   student16
```

Comment: You need to post more of your code.

Comment: You can debug to find what your variable name contains, because IndexOutOfBounds  indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Comment: what you need to know?

Comment: How do you get `reader`, where is your attempt at sorting... do you just want to know how to get `number`?

Comment: BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(infile)));
            
            ArrayList<Student> student= new ArrayList<Student>();

Comment: Edit your question. Include `Student` as well.

Comment: Ok but that is not the problem, the problem is how i can separate the String and the number for each line in the file !!!!!

Comment: `split()` is the wrong tool for the job.  `split` is best suited for when you have a number of fields separated by a common delimiter or delimiter pattern (like spaces or commas).  But you don't have a separator in your input.  Elliott's answer shows the best way to handle this.  I think there are ways to do this with `split()`, but they're a little more complicated and there's no advantage to using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, program to the `List` interface instead of the `ArrayList` concrete type. Second, use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (or explicitly close your `reader` in a `finally` block). Third, I would use a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (a *regex*) and then a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) in the loop to look for "name" and "number". That might look something like,

```
List<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(infile)))) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)(\\d+)");
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(currentLine);
        if (m.matches()) {
            // Assuming `Student` has a `String`, `int` constructor
            student.add(new Student(m.group(1), Integer.parseInt(m.group(2))));
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Finally, note that [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) returns an `Integer` (which you then [unbox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)). That is why I have used [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) here.

Comment: Frisch if I would like to put a try and catch iif the file is not found how can I do it ?

Comment: @ElliottFrish   I need help for you, please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the lines start with `student` and end with a number, you can read all the lines and add them to a `list` and then `sort` the `list` by the number after `student`, then `print` each element. For example:

```
String currentLine;
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    test.add(currentLine());
test.stream()
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(7)) - Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(7)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
student1
student6
student8
student9
```

If you don't want to use `stream()` and `lambda`, You can sort the `list` with a custom `Comparator` then `loop` through the `list` and print each element:

```
Collections.sort(test, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(7));
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(7));
        return n1-n2;
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that code I can used because I already have the comparasion with an interface, I only need to know how can i take the int value for each line and put it in an array.

Comment: @Camila `Integer.parseInt(currentLine.substring(7));` will give you the int value of each line.

Comment: Ok, but if i have student1 student2 student4 student10 student13 student14??? how can i put the string  for student and the ints for each line?

Comment: It will still work, because `substring(7)` gives a `substring` starting with index `7` to the end of the string.

Comment: @MoeA The text "student" is a *name*; not the literal "student".

Comment: I really need help, this is so hard... so, I need to assume that can be different length for the string part, so that is why I only need to solve why the program give me a error !!

Comment: @Camila I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743631/2970947) you eleven minutes ago.

Comment: @Camila if that is the case, Eliott's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: @MoeA Thank you so much you help me a lot :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I need help for an assigment can you help me

Comment: @MoeA can you help me with an assigment?

Comment: @Camila sure, what do you need help with?

Comment: @MoeA I have an assigment for today, i have the code already but i need three things and thats it, is about Graphic Interface in java do you know that topic?

Comment: What are the three things that you want?

Comment: Then start a new question, or let me know where can I see your code

Answer (score -1):

Your file must be like this

```
student 1
student 2
student 3
```

don't forget to add space character between student and number.
And inside your iteration you must add this line: 
`currentLine = reader.readLine();`
you can split like this: `String[] directoryDetail = currentLine.split(" ");` instead of `String[] directoryDetail = currentLine.split("");`
because when you use `String[] directoryDetail = currentLine.split("");` with **student1** the result is a string array of String with length = 0

Comment: Generally, you don't solve programming problems by changing the nature of the input.  That's beyond your control.  The problem is usually "how do I deal with the input I'm given"?